# Job submission takes a lot of time in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have an application written using Apache Flink. It implements feature selections methods based on information theory. For method **mRMR** I have two `DataSet<>`s - one, say **A**, contains selected features and another one, say **B**, contains all other features. When I select a feature, I remove that feature from **B** and add it to **A**. So, I start by calculating mutual information for between classes and features and select a feature with maximum mutual information and add it to **A**. Then I have a `cross()` function to calculate mutual information between all features in **A** and **B**. By doing it, I can adjust mutual information of all features in **B** and select new feature for **A**. I do that for a number of times till I select wanted number of features. I submit the job with the following command:

```
~/Programs/flink-1.4.0/bin/flink run -c org.apache.flink.feast.Main target/flink-feast-1.0.jar --method mrmr --top 5 --input ~/Datasets/00388/data_copy.txt --label 0
```

`--top 5` parameter is used to pass the number of features I want the program to select. In my test dataset, I have 1024 features.

Now, when I want to select 5 features, it works well. When I try to select 15 features, job submission takes 10 minutes and when I try to select 20 features, it takes much more time. Is this behaviour normal? If it is not, what can I do about this issue? I suspect `cross()` function, it is the submission that takes long, not execution. I tried to increase the heap size for job and task managers, but the problem still exists.

Thank you.

Comment: could you show an example of your code?,  the algorithm looks ok, but it's difficult to help you with a slow submission if we don't  know what you are submitting :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what does your `cross()` function, but it looks like it dinamically add operators to Flink Operators Graph using the value of `top`, before Flink runs the job.

In my experience if a job submission takes to much time, it's because the operator graph it's too complex, so Flink needs more time to explore all posible optimizations that can be applyed

Ex:
This take less time to send

```
source -> map -> keyBy -> windows -> reduce -> sink
```

than a complex job like the following

```
               /->filter->flatMap-> keyBy -> windows -> reduce-\
              /-->filter->flatMap-> keyBy -> windows -> reduce--\
source -> map --->filter->flatMap-> keyBy -> windows -> reduce---> join -> sink
              \-->filter->flatMap-> keyBy -> windows -> reduce--/
               \->filter->flatMap-> keyBy -> windows -> reduce-/
```